# Convert a byte array in a datatable column to string?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a datatable customerTbl and I step through the rows

```
foreach (DataRow row in customerTbl.Rows)
{
         string CustomerID = row["Customer ID"].ToString();
}
```

However, the column Customer ID returns byte[]. How can I convert this to a string (CustomerID)?

I tried something like

```
string CustomerID = Convert.ToBase64String(row["Customer ID"]);
```

but it obviously doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `CustomerId` a `byte[]` in the first place?

Comment: What is the customer ID supposed to look like? Is it text? Or just a numeric thing? `Convert.ToBase64String`, does as it says on the package: it converts to a [base64 string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Why do you want to see a string? What for?

Comment: customer id is text and numeric, in the new database we have proper id's but I still need to ship this over for some other referencing. The other database only accepts strings in the column where I want this ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the encoding of the bytes, you'd need the correct `Encoding` object to perform the conversion.  Assuming it is ASCII, you can do this:

```
string customerID = Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])row["Customer ID"]);
```

If in a different encoding (UTF8, UTF16, etc.), use the appropriate one.

Comment: Hi Jeff, with that I get "Error    1    'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and no extension method 'Field' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: You'll need a cast then instead of using the `Field()` extension method.  Since you've added that it's C#2.0, extension methods are not available.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works now. Sorry I forgot to add 2.0 from the beginning.